# Is it possible to handle jQuery input events in Firefox mobile while the keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, jquery, firefox

I am trying to capture input events on a text input. Using jQuery I am handling the `keyup` event to populate a list of matches (an auto-complete list). This works fine on the stock browsers and others such as Maxthon, but in Firefox mobile nothing happens while the keyboard is shown--I have to either press enter or hide the keyboard for it work work.

I am using jQuery 1.7.2, Android 2.3 and the latest version of Firefox (10 I believe). I have also tried other events such as `input` and `keydown` without any luck.

Is it possible to handle key/input events in Firefox mobile while the keyboard is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when word suggestions are turned on in the Android keyboard, Firefox is not triggering the key events during the time the keyboard is "guessing" words, although the values are sent to the text field. I would say this is a bug in Firefox, but I guess they have chosen to do it this way because the result of the key pressed is not consistent with the value the field gets if the keyboard suggests something different than the exact thing you write.

I solved this by using a sniffer that checks on the value if it has changed or not.

```
var $searchField;
var _keypressWatchingTimer = 0;
var _previousTerm = '';

function keypressStartWatching() {
  keypressStopWatching();
  _keypressWatchingTimer = setInterval(executeAutocomplete, 100);
}

function keypressStopWatching() {
  if (_keypressWatchingTimer != 0) {
    clearInterval(_keypressWatchingTimer);
    _keypressWatchingTimer = 0;
  }
}

function executeAutocomplete() {
  var searchTerm = $searchField.val() || '';
  if (_previousTerm == searchTerm)
    return false;
  searchApi.autocomplete(searchTerm);
  _previousTerm = searchTerm;
}

function init() {
  $searchField = $('#searchField')
    .focus(keypressStartWatching)
    .blur(keypressStopWatching)
    .keyup(executeAutocomplete);
}

init();
```

Comment: This project has been completed without FF support, but I will accept this answer as it seems reasonable.